# Clear content for filtered data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I managed to create script to delete rows when it is filtered but not managed to create clear content function when its filtered. Code as below:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('data');
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()

function deleterow_d3() {
  var RANGE = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn)
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  if (sheet.getFilter() != null) {
    sheet.getFilter().remove()
  }

  var filteredRange = RANGE.createFilter()
  var millis_per_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 72; // 3 days
  var today = new Date();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateEqualTo(new Date(today.getTime() - millis_per_day)).setHiddenValues(['']).build();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria); // which column to filter from, criteria is the date
  var deletedrows = lastRow - 3
  sheet.deleteRows(2, deletedrows) // to delete rows
  sheet.getFilter().remove()
}
```

Data is filtered by date then all content within the filter is removed. Instead deleting the rows, i want to clear the content only.

Comment: Tried `.clearContent()`?

Comment: In this line?

`sheet.deleteRows(2, deletedrows) // to delete rows`

Tried and its clearing everything, even not filtered data.

Comment: Yea............

Comment: @TheMaster could you help to Kreng to make the proper code to remove many rows?

Comment: @KrengKongkeng Could you explain this: `I managed to create script to delete rows when it is filtered`? Are you saying unfiltered rows are not deleted, when using your script?

Comment: @YuriKhristich Thing is if delete is done from the UI, the unfiltered rows are not deleted, AFAICT. But, when testing with script, they seem to be.

Comment: Yes unfiltered rows are not deleted when using the above script. Im searching for a way to **clear** the content only without deleting the rows

Comment: @KrengKongkeng I can't reproduce your  effect. But, if what you're saying is true, you can try `RANGE.clearContent()` or `RANGE.offset(1,0).clearContent()` or `sheet.clearContents()`

Comment: @TheMaster Okay, I will do it. (I hope)

Comment: @KrengKongkeng Are you sure only unfiltered rows are deleted? You're deleting from row 2. If the dates that are supposed to be deleted just happen to be in the top few rows, it'll give the illusion that it's deleting correctly. But it's not.

Comment: Yes if using clearContent, all content, even the unfiltered is cleared. Can try using this link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tmxshkilhw47STw016pbEhvP6_ZR9UGnx9fuAoLMNb8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KrengKongkeng Just modify it a little. Copy and paste 5 rows with that date(that should be deleted) at the bottom. It's just coinicidence.

Comment: Ahhh ok i saw it. The update works wonders, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
sheet.deleteRows(2, deletedrows) // to delete rows
```

to:

```
for (var i = 2; i < deletedrows; i++) {
  if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i)) {
    sheet.getRange(i,1,1,lastColumn).clearContent();
  }
}
```

It should work fine for several rows, for a couple dozens rows maybe. But if you have several dozens or hundreds rows to clear this approach is not efficient, it will need a more complicated solution.

**Update**

Here is the example how it can be done in more smart way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var three_days_ago = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 72;
  var data = range.getValues();

  data.forEach((row,i) => {
    if (new Date(row[4]).getTime() == three_days_ago)
      data[i] = new Array(row.length);
  })

  range.setValues(data);
}
```

It takes all the cells from the sheet as a 2d array, cleans rows of the array if date in 5th column == three days ago, and puts the array back on the sheet.

Comment: Umm not working cuz its deleting everything

Comment: Indeed. Well. Then it needs to loop through all the rows and to check if the row is hidden or not. I will change my code

Comment: I just changed my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Or perhaps there should be another condition for the loop `for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)` it depends.

Comment: Is working but looping is taking time.. Just want to find out if theres more straight forward method

Comment: Yes. It's sluggish. For many rows it should be quite different algorithm. Even less straightforward, I'd say. Without the native filter. You have to take all the cells from the sheet as an 2d array. Check and clear the array within the script. And put the array back on the sheet.

Comment: `I hope`....Well that was fast..

Comment: @TheMaster sorry, I had read your comment that you can't reproduce the effect and had though you won't answer. Was I wrong?

Comment: What OP is saying is that when using filter, if A2,A4 and A6 are hidden by the filter, they are NOT deleted, when sheet.deleteRows() is called. He's saying A3,A5 are the only rows that are deleted. I could reproduce this effect manually in the UI, but not his code - it deletes everything A1:A6. In any case, your code should work good!